# Links failed to refresh in Excel. PowerPivot data has failed to refresh

Tags: excel

I have a large Excel file with links and tables that take information from an Access database and format it so that a Power Point can pull the charts. Everytime I click refresh all to refresh all the Access Queries I get an error that says:

> Initialization of the data source failed.
>
> Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external Database is available, and then try the operation again. If you see this message again, create a new data source to connect to the object.

I then click OK and a new message box pops up that reads:

> A PivotTable, cube function or slicer using the connection "PowerPivot Data" has failed to refresh. Continue to refresh all?

I click yes and the rest of the file refreshes. When I investigate further to the PowerPivot Data connection it's description reads:

> This connection is used by Excel for communicatoin between the workbook and embedded PowerPivot data, and should not be manually edited or deleted.

How should I procede? I cant find any power pivot data but I did not create this file. I have been told to resolve this error but am not sure what I can do.

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The power pivot link was to another department's file, they changed the format of it including removing the information I needed. I deleted the powerpivot table and the error was resolved.